# Is the Laurent polynomial ring in several variables an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know the result in 1 variable, using the fact that localization of a PID is also PID. However, for $n>1$ variables, how can we prove it? (I think it is still true.)

The first thing I've got in my mind is the fact that, for given field $k$, $$k[x_{1},x_{1}^{-1}, \dots, x_{n},x_{n}^{-1}] \cong k[x_{1},y_{1}, \dots, x_{n},y_{n}]/ (x_{1}y_{1}-1, \dots, x_{n}y_{n}-1).$$
And it suffices to show that $(x_{1}y_{1}-1, \dots, x_{n}y_{n}-1)$ is prime. However, I have no idea how to show that this ideal is prime. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Just prove that the localization of an integral domain is an integral domain.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know that fact but how can I think Laurent polynomial ring as a localization? I think that localizing $k[x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}]$ with $S=<x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}>$ gives just $k(x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n})$, a field of rational functions not the Laurent polynomial ring...

Comment: Isn't obvious that $k[x_{1},x_{1}^{-1}, \dots, x_{n},x_{n}^{-1}]$ is a subring of the field of fractions of $k[x_{1},\dots, x_{n}]$?

Comment: @user26857 You right.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a PID (which is apparently what your question is asking) but it *is* a domain, (which is what your title is asking.)

$k[X,Y]$ has Krull dimension $2$, and if you localize at the multiplicative set generated by $X$ and $Y$, you're going at least to still have a tower of prime ideals $\{0\}\subseteq (X+1)\subseteq (Y+1)$, so the localization is still $2$ dimensional. But a PID must have Krull dimension $\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned in the comment above, How can I think the Laurent polynomial ring as a localization of something? Actually, I think that $k[x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}]$ with $S=<x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}>$ gives just $k(x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n})$, a field of rational functions not the Laurent polynomial ring...

Comment: @user124697 I think if you think hard about it, you won't see any difference between the description of the set of Laurent polynomials and the localization.  You can just re-express the polynomials as an element of the polynomial ring divided by a product of powers of the $x_i$'s